# How do I create a virtual secondary screen in X11?

Tags: xorg, multi-monitor, xvfb

I'm trying to use xvfb as a secondary screen, but I am struggling getting the two screens working together. xvfb does not seem to have the randr extension.

So is there another possibility to create a virtual screen that could be in dual-head mode together with my real screen?

Answer (score 3):

Xnest does not support randr either. But [Xephyr](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Xephyr) does.

Comment: How exactly do you think `Xephyr` can "extend" Display `:0` with another "graphics device", that OP can position with `xrandr` **relative** to his existing screen? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @AlexStragies See here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Multiseat_Configuration/Xephyr

Comment: Xephyr is nice tech, true, but: The OP is **not** asking for a multi-seat configuration! → Not an answer (to this question).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the xf86-video-dummy driver with Xorg to make the second screen.

Comment: This sounds like a viable idea. Have you tried it? If so, could you elaborate? I'm also following the subject of (hot-)adding virtual graphics devices (with virtual screens). And some details would really make this a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Xnest?  That works by creating a virtual X server that just proxies all of its incoming X protocol calls to the real X server. It also does not support randr, however, so you may want to consider removing your dependency on that (by switching to an alternate window manager or the like).

Comment: That looks good!I will look into using Xnest together with xinerama to archieve my goal. Stupid me: I thought Xnest only was for testing purposes in terms of creating a kind of jail for Xclients. Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: How exactly do you think `Xnest` can "extend" Display `:0` with another "graphics device", that OP can position with `xrandr` **relative** to his existing screen? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: If you had asked me 5 years ago when this question was still fresh in my mind and I was using Xnest regularly, I might be able to answer...